# How to set a value for the url parameter of Connector.open if the target is a local computer?

Tags: java-me

There is a Linux computer which is a web server , and I want to make a HttpConnection to it through the Connector.open method. So if the IP address of the web-server is 192.168.1.123 how to make the HttpConnection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection is made by following:

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

try
{
  HttpConnection connection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

in the above statements url is the url of the service/web,etc.It includes the server ip address , web app name,port,etc.

Thanks & Regards,